# calculate average in python using reduce()

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

Given an sequence of numbers, for example, seq = [2, 4, 2, 4] Then calculate its mean value using reduce and lambda in python.
I've already know one solution:

```
def my_mean(seq):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, seq) / float(len(seq))
```

And then another idea comes to me:

```
def my_mean(seq):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: (x * seq.index(y) + y) / float(seq.index(y) + 1))
```

But the second solution doesn't work.
bad case: seq = [2, 4, 2] returns 2.0 while seq = [2, 2, 4] returns 3.0.In fact, the return values should be the same.
Could you please give me some hints whats wrong with my second solution? Thank you  and sorry for my broken English.

Comment: It doesn't make sense mathematically (it isn't equivalent to your first version) or in code terms.

Comment: How you able to run second example ? Where is second parameter to reduce ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it does, sort of. it's rolling the mean value.

Comment: @Fledgling I missed the second argument of `reduce`. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're missing the second argument of `reduce`: `seq`.

The problem is, `index` will find the first entry. If you have duplicates, that will mess up the calculation.

You can use `enumerate` to fix it, but it's simply not worth it..

Comment: Thank you very much! It stumbled me several hours.I tried the `enumerate` version and it worked! " `index` will find the first entry` - I will keep this in my mind.